# Products being displayed in categories even after removing

Tags: catalog, products-management, category-products

I deleted some products from category but these products are still visible in that particular category on the frontend.This products are not linked to that categories. Please give me an advise Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can reindex for catalog product category

```
php indexer.php --reindex catalog_category_product
```

or from admin view

also don't forget to clear cache.

hoping this will solve your issue.

Comment: Dear liyakat, the problem was different...i had to set the category Anchor to "No" thanks